# How to delete team project folder from source control?

Tags: c#, tfs-sdk

I created folder with [VersionControlServer.CreateTeamProjectFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.createteamprojectfolder.aspx):

```
var connection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://my-tfs-serv:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
var vcs = connection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
vcs.CreateTeamProjectFolder(new TeamProjectFolderOptions("TestFolder"));
```

That call has created folder $/TestFolder/, now I want to delete it.
I could not find API for that. I tried to remove it with

```
TFSDeleteProject.exe /force /collection:http://my-tfs-serv:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection TestFolder
```

But it returns:

> TF200016: The following project does not exist: TestFolder. Verify that the name of  the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Team Foundation Server.

Looks like `VersionControlServer.CreateTeamProjectFolder()` does not create a team project, it just creates the folder only.
But how can i remove that folder now?

Comment: Have you tried using the `tf destroy` command? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

TFSDeleteProject cmd won't work on items created with the code you are using. You can use the following code to delete(destroy):

```
var itemSpec = new ItemSpec(FullRepositoryPath, RecursionType.Full);
                Item[] removedItems = TFSImplementor.VersionControl.Destroy(
                    itemSpec,
                    VersionSpec.Latest,
                    null,
                    DestroyFlags.StartCleanup);
```

TFSDeleteProject cmd will only work on projects created from Wizard.